# finding multiple exact values in an array

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, exact-match

I have an document as shown below with PCL being a keyword

```
  {
    "name": "test",
    "PCL": [
            "product1_company1_location1",
            "product2_company2_location2"
          ]
  }
```

I'm trying to finding the count of all documents that have an exact match to the values given in the array. However , the elastic search docs clearly state there's no 'equals exactly' since 'term' and 'terms' are 'contain operations' and the proposed solution of using count will not work here since a user can have as many elements in the array.

I tried making PCL field into a string delimited by a character to differentiate between each PCL , but if the order of the string aren't the same , for instance,P1C1L1_P2C2L2 vs P2C2L2_P1C1L1 ,users with the same PCL are not likely to see the other documents.

Here's the query I'm trying to work around

```
   GET indexName/_search
   {
    "query": {
     "bool": {
      "should": [
       {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "PCL": [
                    "product1_company1_vendor1",
                    "product2_company2_vendor2"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
         },
         {
           "bool": {
             "must": [
               {
                 "terms": {
                   "PCL": [
                     "product1_company1_vendor_1",
                     "product3_company3_vendor_3"
                   ]
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
          }
        ]
      }
     },
     "aggs": {
      "PCL": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "PCL"
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

Is there anyway to achieve this using Elasticsearch?
 (note: I've decided to sort the PCL so there isn't an order conflict and store it as a string since an exact match within the array isn't possible)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get exact match, You have to enclose the search string in `"`.This will ensure to retrieve exact match results.

eg:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "PCL": [
           "\"product1_company1_location1\"",
           "\"product2_company2_location2\""
         ]
}
```

Comment: Hi , This inserts a document with multiple quotation marks . In short , it created an array of elements with extra quotes around each element. So an exact match within the array wasn't possible.